# many to many association. Datas doesn't delete

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have this model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "candidate")
@XmlRootElement(name = "candidate")
public class Candidate{
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "candidates", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @XmlTransient
    public Set<Vacancy> getVacancies() {
        return vacancies;
    }
....
}
```

and back mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vacancy")
@XmlRootElement(name="vacancy")
public class Vacancy {@ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "vacancy_candidate", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "vacancy_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id"))
    public Set<Candidate> getCandidates() {
        return candidates;
    }
    ...
}
```

And I have so Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping("/saveCandidate")
public String saveCandidate(
        Model model,
        @ModelAttribute("candidateFromRequest") Candidate candidateFromRequest,

        @ModelAttribute("vacanciesForCandidate") Set<Vacancy> vacanciesForCandidate,

        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    candidateService.updateCandidateAndLinkedEntities(candidateFromRequest,
            vacanciesForCandidate,...);
    ...
}
```

next level:

```
    @Transactional
    @Service("candidateService")
    public class CandidateService {
    public void updateCandidateAndLinkedEntities(Candidate candidate,
                Set<Vacancy> vacancies, ...) {

            if (candidate == null)
                throw new NullPointerException("null candidate entity");


            if (vacancies != null) {

                candidate.setVacancies(vacancies);

                for (Vacancy vacancy : vacancies) {
                    vacancy.getCandidates().add(candidate);
                    vacancyDao.update(vacancy);
                }
            }
            candidateDao.update(candidate);//here all right, how I wish(I am about state of candidate entity)

        }
        ...
    }
```

update methods realization:

vacancy:

```
@Override
    public boolean update(Vacancy vacancy) throws HibernateException {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        if (vacancy == null) {
            return false;
        }
        session.update(vacancy);
        return true;

    }
```

candidate:

```
@Override
    public boolean update(Candidate candidate) throws HibernateException{
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        if (candidate == null) {
            return false;
        }
        session.update(candidate);

        return true;

    }
```

I have strange behavior. If I add new Vacancy to Candidate - it works good. But if I delete  vacancies - it doesn't works.

It is doesn't understand for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove the Vacancy from the list of the Candidate, don't forget to remove the Candidate from the List of the Vacancy, and vice versa. Also bear in mind: if there is somewhere a place in your system, that send later the already-deleted Vacancy (or vice versa), that entity will be again persisted.