# JPA - Issues removing child entities on bidirectional mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need to remove a **child** entity called "SystemParamater" based on the it´s id.

What i was trying to do:

```
- Begin Tran
  SystemParameter param EntityManager.find(SystemParameter.class,<paremeter.id>)
  EntityManager.remove(param)
-Commit tran
```

But the entity was not removed.

What´s the correct way to remove a child entity?

Below, you could find my entities:

SystemParameter:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "system_parameters")
@Cacheab le
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class SystemParameter extends BasicEntity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -6416605270912358340L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "paramName", length = 50, nullable = false)
private String paramName;

@Column(name = "paramValue", length = 255, nullable = false)
private String paramValue;

@Column(name = "encrypted", nullable = false)
@Type(type = "yes_no")
private Boolean encrypted = Boolean.FALSE;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "groupId", nullable = false)
private SystemParameterGroup parameterGroup;
}
```

SystemParameterGroup:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "system_parameter_groups", uniqueConstraints = {     @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "searchKey" }) })
@Cacheable
public class SystemParameterGroup extends BasicEntity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1762633144642103487L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", length = 50, nullable = false)
private String name;
/**
 * Description.
 */
@Column(name = "description", length = 255, nullable = false)
private String description;
/**
 * Search key.
 */
@Column(name = "searchKey", length = 50, nullable = false)
private String searchKey;
/**
 * System parameter list.
 */
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parameterGroup", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@OrderBy("paramName")
private List<SystemParameter> systemParameterList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the `SystemParameter` entity also from the `SystemParameterGroup`'s list of `SystemParameter`:

```
systemParameterGroup.getSystemParameterList().remove(systemParameter);
```

This issue is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828143/many-to-many-association-datas-doesnt-delete/18829654#18829654).